# R filter by column number rather than name

Tags: r

I have the below code that filters a table based on a column called date and shows all cases within 28 day period:

```
 TableOutput <- Table %>%
  select(areaType, date, cases) %>%
  filter(date %in% (max(date)-27):max(date))
```

I would like to select by the number of the date column, which is column 12. My attempts result in errors, can anyone correct please?

Comment: Please share a part of your data `Table`, best using `dput(head(Table))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to address the specific query without input and expected output but in general you can use `across` within `filter` to specify column number.  As long as the `filter` is not within a `group_by/ungroup` the `cur_data()` and . alternatives below work too. This returns all rows for which the 8th column exceeds 7.5 .  (`anscombe` comes with R.)

```
anscombe %>% filter(across(8) > 7.5)

anscombe %>% filter(cur_data()[[8]] > 7.5)

anscombe %>% filter(.[[8]] > 7.5)
```

Any of these give:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4   y1   y2    y3    y4
1 13 13 13  8 7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
2  9  9  9  8 8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
3 11 11 11  8 8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
4  4  4  4 19 4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
5  7  7  7  8 4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html) confirms that `filter(across())` is indeed the ticket!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
Table %>% filter_at(12, ~ .x %in% (max(date)-27):max(date))
```

Comment: Just FYI: [`dplyr::filter_at()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html) is [superseded](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/stages.html#superseded) in favor of [`dplyr::across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), as used within [`dplyr::filter()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html).

Comment: Thanks - problem is if I change to that then I get error: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Comment: I can not reproduce your error bc you have not provided example data using dput

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone, very much appreciated. Below solution works, just needed correct brackets and defining the referenced column in all three necessary places. Thank you!

```
TableOutput <- Table %>%
      select(areaType, date, cases) %>%
      filter(.[[12]] %in% (max(.[[12]])-27):max(.[[12]]))
```